# Add days to current date

Tags: java, date, datetime

Here is my code

```
 public java.util.Date getDelDate() {
    Date m=new Date();
    System.out.println("ticket date "+ m);
    double d;
    d=(multiply/consumption);
    int days= (int) d;
    System.out.println("del days "+ days);
    m.setTime(m.getTime() + days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    System.out.println(m+"Delivery date");
    return m;
}
public java.util.Date getRemDate() {
    Date m1=new Date();
    double d;
    d=(multiply/consumption);
    int days= (int) d-2;
    System.out.println("rem days "+ days);
    m1.setTime(m1.getTime() + days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    System.out.println(m1+"Remember date");
    return m1;
    //return remdate;
}
```

for Input values of `multiply = 21` and `consumption = 2`
the output is (correct as follows)

```
ticket date Wed Oct 02 21:43:56 IST 2013
del days 10
Sat Oct 12 21:43:56 IST 2013Delivery date
rem days 8
```

for Input values of `multiply = 35` and `consumption = 1`
the output is (wrong as follows showing old date)

```
ticket date Wed Oct 02 21:52:07 IST 2013
del days 35
Wed Sep 18 04:49:20 IST 2013Delivery date
rem days 33
Mon Sep 16 04:49:20 IST 2013Remember date
```

for Input values of `multiply = 1` and `consumption = 0.03`
the output is (wrong as follows showing old date)

```
ticket date Wed Oct 02 21:26:56 IST 2013
del days 33
Mon Sep 16 04:24:09 IST 2013Delivery date   //date here is sept?
rem days 31
Sat Sep 14 04:24:09 IST 2013Remember date
```

how do i calculate the correct date?

Comment: maybe checkout Joda Time: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/   -- it's a much easier time/date api/lib to use than the built-in stuff.

Comment: im using javaPOS no i cannot use jodatime :(

Comment: What does this have to do with JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are behind the max value of an int so you get a negative value :S

Change the `int days` for `long days`

Y listo!

Comment: it worked.. ty :) but y was that hapening? can u say in short?

Comment: getTime returns a long because the max possible value of an int is too low. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Java does not have unsigned integers, so the max value of int is 2^31 - 1, or 2147483647. Going beyond that results in negatives.

Comment: Actually, going beyond does not always return negative. If you go 2.5 time the limit, you it will return 0.5 the limit. When limit is reached, it just continue, starting from the minimum (negative) value. It doing loop from min value to max value.

Comment: @CedricSimon thnx for that :)

Comment: @CedricSimon I think it's safe to just say "It overflows, and results in undefined behavior". -- ah.. taking me back to my C days... darn overflows...

Comment: Actually, behavior is defined. Try with a byte. Set it to 129, it will return -127. Set it to 256, it will return 0 ;)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use a Calendar. An implementation is part of java.

To add days or to subtract days you use the same method add():

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int days = 35;
    // Add days
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
}
```

If you want to subtract days, just use a negative number of days.

Comment: Using Calendar is best way of managing dates. Unfortunately, it requires more lines of codes than java.util.Date... But lots of methods in Date object are deprecated in favor of the Calendar object.